# How does the Meteor.method Optimistic UI work?

Tags: meteor

Is this question duplicated maybe? I cannot find what I want from other answers.

My understands are

- Methods runs twice. First on the client (this.isSimulation=true), next on the server.
- The client has stub methods.

Questions are

1. How can the client has stub methods? The client has built with `server/main.js`? Or the server sends methods as strings?
2. The client stub method has same imports/scopes with server?
3. I've put some `consone.log` on a method. These are not printed on the client. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it is a duplicate. All your answers are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30475494/7733460

Moreover, you can study further here: https://learn-meteor.netlify.app/
Specifically, go to Meteor/Core/4. RPC with Meteor Methods, chapter 7